# How to compare a column value in one row to column value in another row in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, case-statement

I'm working with `Postgresql 8.0`. I have a table as follows:

Table1:

```
ID  | Val | Num | Val2

ABC | High | 22 | Low
ABC | Low  | 2  | High
ABC | High | 16 | Low
DFG | High | 10 | High
DFG | High | 50 | High
DFG | Low  | 3  | High
EGF | Low  | 2  | High
2BD | Low  | 34  | High
2BD | High  | 2  | High
```

How can I get an output where for the same `ID`s in the first column, it checks the `Val` column, gives high precedence to `'High'` value than `'Low'` or `'Mod'` and then from among the rows for that `ID` with `'High'` in the Val column select the row with higher value in the `'Num'` column. For the above sample the output should be as follows:

```
ID | Val | Num | Val2

ABC | High | 22 | Low
DFG | High | 50 | High
EGF | Low  | 2  | High
2BD | High  | 2  | High
```

Can someone guide me how to achieve this?

I'm trying it this way:

```
select a.ID, a.Val, a.Num, a.Val2

from

(select * from table1 where Val = ‘High’) a JOIN

(select * from table1 where Val = ‘High’) b ON

a.ID = b.ID
where a.Num > b.Num
```

But this will eliminate the `EGF` row from the output as well!!

Comment: Have you tried any code yourself at all?

Comment: @Ibo Yes please see my update in the question.

Comment: First of, it's highly unconventional to have an ID column that's not a primary key, but it looks like you need to be using WINDOW functions instead of joins. But with Postgres 8 that's probably not supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select id, max(num) val, val2
 from table1
 group by id, val2
```

Comment: Well what if a 'Low' has a higher Num value? This will make us select that num value however we want the one corresponding to the 'High'

Comment: Maybe so-- I don't really understand what your data represents so it's hard to guess.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what your data represents.. and I'm not fully understanding. Can you give some more data and explain why my query wouldn't work-- that way I can give you a query that will give you what you expect...

Comment: Okay, so I added two more rows in the sample table above. So for ID '2BD', the row with 'Low' has a Num value of 34, whereas the row with 'High' value has a Num value of 2, but in this case I'd want the latter row to be selected. Basically, I always want 'High' value in the Val column row to be selected unless, some ID does not have any 'High' in the Val column at all. Then if a ID has multiple 'High' Vals then select the row with higher 'Num'. Do you understand now? Please see from the desired output above.